# NameError in Tensorflow and Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

This line indicates that the code started the processing part,
"Processing images/Young-Bengal-tiger.jpg...".

I am trying to solve the error below:

```
In [50]: def extract_features(list_images):
    ...:   nb_features = 2048
    ...:   features = np.empty((len(list_images),nb_features))
    ...:   labels = []
    ...: 
    ...:   create_graph()
    ...: 
    ...:   with tf.Session() as sess:
    ...: 
    ...:       next_to_last_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')
    ...: 
    ...: for ind, image in enumerate(list_images):
    ...:     if (ind%100 == 0):
    ...:         print('Processing %s...' % (image))
    ...: if not gfile.Exists(image):
    ...:     tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)
    ...: 
    ...:     image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()
    ...:     predictions = sess.run(next_to_last_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
    ...: features[ind,:] = np.squeeze(predictions)
    ...: labels.append(re.split('_\d+',image.split('/')[1])[0])
    ...: 
    ...: return features, labels
Processing images/Young-Bengal-tiger.jpg...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-ba615e05226c> in <module>()
     18     image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()
     19     predictions = sess.run(next_to_last_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
---> 20 features[ind,:] = np.squeeze(predictions)
     21 labels.append(re.split('_\d+',image.split('/')[1])[0])
     22 

NameError: name 'predictions' is not defined
```

Comment: What is `predictions` if the image file *does* exist?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the readiness of your answer. The error messages says that the code is processing one image " images/Young-Bengal-tiger.jpg".  This section of the code didn't indicate any that an image was missing: if not gfile.Exists(image):
    ...:     tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)

Comment: if not gfile.Exists(image):
    ...:     tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)

Comment: When I go print (image_data)...I get the following, meaning that "predictions" has the parameters.                                                                          Z�
                     $w�k�p��L\) ��?����x�I�/����+�`��2��X��V,�+q��kJ0zF��3�廱λ��Y���9$�QEw�EPEPv������T�QR�C{�QT"Σ�]���]��O{u&7�q!���$���*�R��)�QEQEQE�

Comment: Daniel is right. To be clear, it's quite probably that `image_data` and `predictions` are mis-indented. Right now they are in the if branch when the file does not exist.

Comment: Please add extra information into the question itself, by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I followed your recomendations and I solved my question by getting a better identation.